# Multiple subqueries with joins and calculation by column alias in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, subquery, calculated-columns

**Using SQL Server 2008**

**PROBLEM**
I have inherited some code that contains nested subqueries with joins.
I now need to add an output column that performs a calculation on two columns already in the table. 
The combination of (subqueries, joins, column aliasing) > Me. Thanks for help!

**CURRENT CODE**

```
SELECT TABLE1.externalid, TABLE1.startdate, TABLE1.enddate, TABLE1.Price,
    DATEDIFF(D,TABLE1.startdate,TABLE1.enddate) AS [Days],
    TABLE2.UserDefinedIndex, TABLE2.commodity, 


     (SELECT TOP 1 DATE 
        FROM (SELECT TOP
                (SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE COUNT(*) END -1 
                FROM TABLE3 WHERE UserDefinedIndex = 'L'  AND DATE < TABLE1.startdate
                    AND  DATE BETWEEN CAST(Table1.startdate as datetime)-6 AND TABLE1.startdate 
            )* 
            FROM TABLE3 WHERE UserDefinedIndex = 'L' AND DATE < TABLE1.startdate 
                AND DATE BETWEEN CAST(TABLE1.startdate as datetime)-6 AND TABLE1.startdate
                ORDER BY DATE
            ) AS A ORDER BY DATE DESC
        )     AS Final_Pricing_Date,

     (SELECT TOP 1 PRICE 
        FROM (SELECT TOP 
                (SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE COUNT(*) END -1 
                FROM TABLE3 WHERE UserDefinedIndex = 'L' AND DATE < TABLE1.startdate
                    AND DATE BETWEEN CAST(Table1.startdate as datetime)-6 AND TABLE1.startdate  
                )*
             FROM TABLE3  WHERE UserDefinedIndex = 'L' AND DATE < TABLE1.startdate 
                AND DATE BETWEEN CAST(TABLE1.startdate as datetime)-6 AND TABLE1.startdate ORDER BY DATE
            )   AS A ORDER BY DATE DESC
        )/100   AS Final_Price

FROM  TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2
    ON TABLE1.underlying= TABLE2.underlying
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**
I need something that will allow me to return a calculation on [Final_Price]. 
Current output columns are:
        externalid, startdate, enddate, Price, Days, UserDefinedIndex, commodity, Final_Pricing_Date, Final_Price

I want to add column [PriceDelta] at the end, which would be
        TABLE1.Price - Final_Price

Thanks!

Comment: One of the better questions I have seen.  Very well organized and to the point!  I wish I could give you more up-votes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way without completely rewriting the query is to use another subquery, wrap the entire existing query and then using the columns of the inner query for the calculation.

```
SELECT  A.*,
        A.Price - A.[Final_Price] AS [PriceDelta]
FROM (
        SELECT TABLE1.externalid, TABLE1.startdate, TABLE1.enddate, TABLE1.Price,
            DATEDIFF(D,TABLE1.startdate,TABLE1.enddate) AS [Days],
            TABLE2.UserDefinedIndex, TABLE2.commodity, 


             (SELECT TOP 1 DATE 
                FROM (SELECT TOP
                        (SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE COUNT(*) END -1 
                        FROM TABLE3 WHERE UserDefinedIndex = 'L'  AND DATE < TABLE1.startdate
                            AND  DATE BETWEEN CAST(Table1.startdate as datetime)-6 AND TABLE1.startdate 
                    )* 
                    FROM TABLE3 WHERE UserDefinedIndex = 'L' AND DATE < TABLE1.startdate 
                        AND DATE BETWEEN CAST(TABLE1.startdate as datetime)-6 AND TABLE1.startdate
                        ORDER BY DATE
                    ) AS A ORDER BY DATE DESC
                )     AS Final_Pricing_Date,

             (SELECT TOP 1 PRICE 
                FROM (SELECT TOP 
                        (SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE COUNT(*) END -1 
                        FROM TABLE3 WHERE UserDefinedIndex = 'L' AND DATE < TABLE1.startdate
                            AND DATE BETWEEN CAST(Table1.startdate as datetime)-6 AND TABLE1.startdate  
                        )*
                     FROM TABLE3  WHERE UserDefinedIndex = 'L' AND DATE < TABLE1.startdate 
                        AND DATE BETWEEN CAST(TABLE1.startdate as datetime)-6 AND TABLE1.startdate ORDER BY DATE
                    )   AS A ORDER BY DATE DESC
                )/100   AS Final_Price

        FROM  TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2
            ON TABLE1.underlying= TABLE2.underlying
    ) AS A
```

Comment: Super easy-to-implement. Thanks